# jquery-ui autocomplete: set source by callback function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

link to fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nEapJ/ (working)

```
var items = [{
   label : 'a',
   value : 'a',
},{
   label : 'b',
   value : 'b',
},{
   label : 'c',
   value : 'c',
}];

$('input').autocomplete({
    source : items
});​
```

This code works, but when i want to set source by callback function
then
It's not working

link to fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/B3RWj/ (not working)

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response){
            response(items);
          }
});​
```

when i type, 'a' then its give a,b,c as result.

So, what am I missing?

thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the callback function it's up to you to do the filtering..

Extract from [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and
>   can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback
>   gets two arguments:
>
> A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers
>   to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user
>   entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal
>   "new yo". A response callback, which expects a single argument to
>   contain the data to suggest to the user. **This data should be filtered
>   based on the provided term**, and can be in any of the formats described
>   above for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with
>   label/value/both properties). It's important when providing a custom
>   source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always
>   call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This
>   ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Comment: i think, jquery-ui autocomplete auto filter by typed charcters by matching with label key in given source..

Comment: actually, it auto filters only for *local source* option

Answer (score 2):

see the code:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response){
        var term = request.term;
        var result = [];

        //make your code here to filter the item by term. 
        //put them into the result array such as.

        response(result);//this will show in the selection box.
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the callback function instead of a source array or string you have to add
`response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(items, request.term));`

in the your function:

`source : function(request, response){}`

This is what autocomplete does when you define your source as an array or string, but for callbacks you have to add this.